# How can i restore a mimetypes file? electrum Error: No module named mimetypes

Tags: apt, python

I removed some "wrong" mimetypes files. How can I resolve this error? Reinstalling electrum and pip hasn't solved this.

```
$ electrum
Error: No module named mimetypes. Try 'sudo pip install <module-name>'

$ sudo pip install mimetypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point(pip==1.5.6', console_scripts', pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py, line 5, in <module>
    import mimetypes
ImportError: No module named mimetypes
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what files you removed? FYI `/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py` is provided by the `libpython2.7-stdlib` package

Comment: what's with the debian tag?

Comment: I dont remember, but  /usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py is missing. If i reinstall libphyton2.7 it is can solve this error?

Comment: Problem solved! I made missing mimetypes.py from github, after (maybie not necessary) made sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I made missing mimetypes.py from github, after (maybie not necessary) made sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7